# Why does the sequence of parameters matter in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I think this is entry-level, but I haven't googled any answer out..

When building queries, do we have to use the :1, :2... stuff in an absolute sequence? From my tests, it seems yes. But doesn't calling stmt->setXXX(n, val) just set the nth parameter in the statement with val? How is it implemented?

Please see my example below:

```
    if (bNewContent)    //new
    {
        sql = "BEGIN PackProductManagement.procAddOTTContent(:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7); END; ";
    }
    else                //update
    {
        sql = "UPDATE OTT_Content SET ContentID = :1, ContentType = :2, FingerPrint = :3, IsHighLevelSafe = :4, ";
        sql += "OutProtection = :5, OfflinePlayback = :6, ModifyTime = sysdate ";
        sql += "WHERE ContentID = :1";
    }
    try
    {
        OpenStatement(sql);
        stmt->setString(1, ac->ContentDesc.ContentID);
        stmt->setUInt(2, ac->ContentDesc.ContentType);
        stmt->setUInt(3, ac->ContentDesc.FingerPrint);
        stmt->setUInt(4, ac->ContentDesc.HighLevelSafe);
        stmt->setUInt(5, ac->ContentDesc.OutputProtection);
        stmt->setUInt(6, ac->ContentDesc.OfflinePlayback);
        if (bNewContent)
        {
            stmt->setUInt(7, 0);        //only used if new
        }
        stmt->execute();

        CloseStatement(true);
    }
```

In this example, `bNewContent` is always FALSE, so we're always running the update statement. The above query works OK. But if I change the update query like below (removed `ContentID = :1,` at the beginning of the update statement), I'll get an ORA-01722 INVALID_NUMBER. Why can't I do :2:3:4:5:6:1? If setXXX is implemented like a queue, why the above :1:2:3:4:5:6:1 work??

```
sql = "UPDATE OTT_Content SET  ContentType = :2, FingerPrint = :3, IsHighLevelSafe = :4, ";
sql += "OutProtection = :5, OfflinePlayback = :6, ModifyTime = sysdate ";
sql += "WHERE ContentID = :1";
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edited:**

Test results below: (based on ZZa's answer)

```
sql = "UPDATE OTT_Content SET ContentID = :x ContentType = :x, FingerPrint = :x, IsHighLevelSafe = :x, ";
sql += "OutProtection = :x, OfflinePlayback = :x, ModifyTime = sysdate ";
sql += "WHERE ContentID = :x";
```

Above code doesn't work with 6 parameters.

```
sql = "UPDATE OTT_Content SET ContentID = :1 ContentType = :x, FingerPrint = :x, IsHighLevelSafe = :x, ";
sql += "OutProtection = :x, OfflinePlayback = :x, ModifyTime = sysdate ";
sql += "WHERE ContentID = :1";
```

Above code works with 6 parameters.

Comment: Eh.  It doesn't matter in SQL.  It might matter in *Oracle*...but SQL Server and Postgres, at the very least, can actually *name* their parameters.  This `:1` crap is for the birds.  :P

Comment: I take that back...PostgreSQL actually does `$1`, `$2` etc.  But there's nothing in the docs about them having to be used in sequence.

Comment: Which driver are you using? The bind by name/position behaviour varies, but here it's clearly binding by position and the 'names' of the parameters are ignored; `:1` is a paramater *named* `1` in this context, not parameter number one. (You don't have a `:7`, but you use `setXXX(7, ...)`).

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the explanation! I'm running Oracle(11gR1) on a SUSE machine.. I tried lsmod to check about the driver, but not sure which one should I be looking at. (The :7 is conditional, not used in the Update statement)

Comment: D'oh, yes I noticed 7 wasn't used, then forgot, sorry. I've answered a question like this before (similar to ZZa's answer) but can't find it for some reason. The bit that seems weird is that the second reference to `:1` works.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Not talking about functions here, but about prepared statements. The PG docs on [`PREPARE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/sql-prepare.html) and on [`PQprepare`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQPREPARE) don't mention the ability to use anything other than `$1` etc for the params.  I remember using named params before, but it looks like it might have been just a feature of the DB abstraction layer i was using (PDO).

Comment: @cHao: ah. Sorry, I misunderstood that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [ORACLE documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-4E5C6A4F-C1DB-44DD-964E-C683120B448E) bind variables are used in the order they were placed, but not how they were named. That's why you get an exception. So, you just need to set parameters in the order they were mentioned (the first mentioned is `ContentType` in the case you remove the first), and it doesn't matter how they're named.

Your code could look like this and it still would certainly work:

```
if (bNewContent)    //new
{
    sql = "BEGIN PackProductManagement.procAddOTTContent(:x, :x, :x, :x, :x, :x, :x); END; ";
}
else                //update
{
    sql = "UPDATE OTT_Content SET ContentID = :x, ContentType = :x, FingerPrint = :x, IsHighLevelSafe = :x, ";
    sql += "OutProtection = :x, OfflinePlayback = :x, ModifyTime = sysdate ";
    sql += "WHERE ContentID = :x";
}
try
{
    OpenStatement(sql);
    stmt->setString(1, ac->ContentDesc.ContentID);
    stmt->setUInt(2, ac->ContentDesc.ContentType);
    stmt->setUInt(3, ac->ContentDesc.FingerPrint);
    stmt->setUInt(4, ac->ContentDesc.HighLevelSafe);
    stmt->setUInt(5, ac->ContentDesc.OutputProtection);
    stmt->setUInt(6, ac->ContentDesc.OfflinePlayback);
    if (bNewContent)
    {
        stmt->setUInt(7, 0);        //only used if new
    }
    stmt->execute();

    CloseStatement(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. You're right! With further testings, it turned out that the sequence to call setXXX in the code(C++ here) doesn't matter, but the n in setXXX(n, val) has to match with the order they were mentioned in the query. Also, it seems that for some reason, the DB partially treats the parameter name as 'name in the WHERE clause, since the `:1` in WHERE is substituted in my test (see updated post...).

Comment: We converted from the NET integrated Oracle driver to the managed(nuget). The app constantly throwed ORA-1722 not a number. After reading this we realized that the first arg(index) and the "name" in parameters are completely ignored in TSQL. Many thanks for pointing this out. Updated the link to v19.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, it depends.

If you are using .net and odbc you have to use positional parameters.  If you are using .net and sql server you can use named parameters.  If you are using the cfstoredproc tag in ColdFusion, you have to use positional parameters.

And so on and so forth.

Comment: Thanks @Dan! I'm running the test in linux with oracle DB, any detailed documents that I can learn from? I only found [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28390/relational.htm) about setXXXs, but it doesn't say anything about the position..